# Scattering of relativistic particle by long-range potential

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let

$\mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$,

$H_0=\sqrt{-\Delta+M^2}$, ($M$ is a positive constant, $\Delta$ is the laplacian)

and

$H=H_0+V(\vec{x})$

(where $V(\vec{x})$ is the operator of multiplication by a bounded continuous function $V(\vec{x})$; $H$ is a perturbation of $H_0$ by a bounded operator).

Consider the operators
$$\exp(it H)\exp(-itH_0)\Psi, $$
where $\Psi\in\mathcal{H}$.

If $V$ is square-integrable then it is relatively easy to show (using the Cook's method) that the limit 
$$\Omega_\pm=\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\exp(it H)\exp(-it H_0)\Psi$$
exists.

If $V(\vec{x})$ is a long-range potental, i.e. it vanishes in infinity not faster than the Coulomb potential $(1/|\vec{x}|)$ than the above limit does not exist. The above expression has to be modified.

Scattering of a non-relativistic particle by a long-range potential: 
If $H_0=-\Delta$ than 
$$\Omega_\pm=\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\exp(it H)U_{as}(t)\Psi$$
exists, where $U_{as}$ is the the asymptotic evolution operator (describing 'distorted free' propagation of a particle in a potential $V$). This generalization was first proposed by Dollard in case of the potential $V(\vec{x})=\frac{const}{|\vec{x}|}$. Nowadays the theory of scattering of a non-relativistic particle by a long-range potential is well-developed.

I'm interested in a similar results in the relativistic case, i.e. $H_0=\sqrt{-\Delta+M^2}$ and $V$ is a long-range potential (vanishing in infinity like Coulomb potential). Is there a 'modified free' evolution operator $U_{as}(t)$ such that
$$\Omega_\pm=\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\exp(it H)U_{as}(t)\Psi$$
exists.

I will be grateful for any references and comments.

Comment: Why doesn't Hörmander's method apply to $H_0$ ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Does this method apply to $H_0=(-\Delta+m^2)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that long-range scattering for the operator $\sqrt{-\Delta+M^2}$ has not been dealt with in the literature. On the technical side, I would start with Chapter XXX of Hörmander [*The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators IV*](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642001178), where long-range scattering for general $m$th-order elliptic differential operators is discussed.

There are a few papers on long-range scattering for Dirac operators, though. For instance, existence and completeness of the wave operators is treated by [Gâtel and Yafaev (2001)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123601937425) which was improved by [Daudé (2005)](https://eudml.org/doc/116167) using time-dependent observables as introduced by Dereziński and Gérard [*Scattering Theory of Classical and Quantum $N$-Particle Systems*](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540620662).